# Type object as extension of other type

Tags: typescript, types

I want to create an object that has a set of "base" properties, but also other properties. Moreover I want to export the type of this new object using `typeof`. I also want to not define an interface for this object, because properties are periodically added to the object and I would like to not have to update both the object AND the interface.

- Compile-error if a property is added to `Base` but not to `derived`
- Export the type of `derived` with all properties
- No type/interface for `derived`

```js
export type Base = {
  id: string;
}

// elsewhere

export const derived = {
  id: "42",
  foo: "bar"
}
```

If I create the object without any type information at all, I of course will not receive compile-errors if it does not comply with `Base`.

The first naive attempt is to just type `derived` as `Base`:

```js
export const derived: Base = {
  id: "42",
  foo: "bar" // error: type { ... } is not assignable to { ... }
}

export type Derived = typeof derived; // This should be { id: string; foo: string }
```

Here the compiler is of course complaining because I have typed `derived` to be `Base`, but I have added properties that are not a part of `Base`.

Instead I can type `derived` to be `Base` and additional unknown properties using for instance `Record<string, unknown>`:

```js
export const derived: Record<string, unknown> & Base = {
  id: "42",
  foo: "bar"
}

export type Derived = typeof derived; // Now: Record<string, unknown> & { id: string; }
```

Now when I do `typeof derived`, I unfortunately get back the type I just defined, so the `foo` property is not captured, because the type dictates that `foo` is just a key in an arbitrary record and that record.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is a kind of a hack, where I create an unused variable of type `Base` and assign `derived` to it, *just* to get type-checking.

```js
export const derived = {
  id: "42",
  foo: "bar"
}

export type Derived = typeof derived; // This type is now correct

const _: Base = derived; // This will error if derived is not implementing Base correctly
```

I was hoping there was a way to type `derived` to arbitrarily extend  `Base` without losing type information with `typeof`. Is such a type possible?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCBDAzqgvHAbwFgAoOOASwBMAuOLGKCgOwHMBuUgX05NIGMIzBnH5RgGGMAAiwJgDdgVOPgA8AFTigpzKlnTZgAPgAUAI0N11AShVG4FnL1KhIsUUJFU5FRcvxiElKyCkomxGSUtHAA5AAsAEwxADSk5ABmEBB0MRZQKdzWziSu0PBIKHAhvkoqCMjAEOlw3qFUvEA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @wonderflame, your workaround is similar to mine but better (no floating unused variable). I think Lesiak has an even better answer though because it only uses the type system (no auxilliary functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [satisfies operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator)

```ts
export type Base = {
  id: string;
}

export const derived = {
  id: "42",
  foo: "bar"
} satisfies Record<string, unknown> & Base;

export type Derived = typeof derived;

// type Derived = {
//   id: string;
//   foo: string;
// }
```

or even:

```ts
export const derived = {
  id: "42",
  foo: "bar"
} as const satisfies Record<string, unknown> & Base;

export type Derived = typeof derived;

// type Derived = {
//   readonly id: "42";
//   readonly foo: "bar";
// }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Was not aware of the `satisfies` operator :)